# Excel count if of colums to be included in row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, excel-formula

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['BAT', 'BWL', 'ALLR'])
df['1'] = ['BWL', 'BAT', 'ALLR']
df['2'] = ['BAT', 'BAT', 'WK']

df

    0    1     2
0   BAT  BWL  BAT
1   BWL  BAT  BAT
2   ALLR ALLR WK
```

How to add columns named 'BAT','BWL','ALL', and 'WK' with the count the number of BAT/BWL/ALLR/WK appearing as the value of cells for all the rows? I have over 100k rows hence want to use Pandas

The final table should look like the following.

```
    0    1     2   BAT BWL ALLR WK
0   BAT  BWL  BAT   2  1    0   0
1   BWL  BAT  BAT   2  1    0   0
2   ALLR ALLR WK    0  0    2   1
```

Comment: There are many other coloumns also of which i dont need the count. e.g. df=pd.DataFrame(['BAT', 'BWL', 'ALLR']) df['1']=['BWL', 'BAT', 'ALLR'] df['2']=['BAT', 'BAT', 'WK'] df['3']=['A', 'B', 'C'] df #i dont need count of 'A','B','C, . Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `stack`  +`get_dummies`

```
df=df.join(df[['colyour need']].stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0))
df
Out[100]: 
      0     1    2  ALLR  BAT  BWL  WK
0   BAT   BWL  BAT     0    2    1   0
1   BWL   BAT  BAT     0    2    1   0
2  ALLR  ALLR   WK     2    0    0   1
```

Comment: There are many other coloumns also of which i dont need the count. e.g. df=pd.DataFrame(['BAT', 'BWL', 'ALLR'])
df['1']=['BWL', 'BAT', 'ALLR']
df['2']=['BAT', 'BAT', 'WK']
df['3']=['A', 'B', 'C']
df       #i dont need count of 'A','B','C, . Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @rakesh filter before stack df[['colyour need']].

Answer (score 1):

Similar to YOBEN_S's answer , with `pd.get_dummies` with `groupby` on `axis=1` and `sum`:

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df).groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1],axis=1).sum())
```

---

```
      0     1    2  ALLR  BAT  BWL  WK
0   BAT   BWL  BAT     0    2    1   0
1   BWL   BAT  BAT     0    2    1   0
2  ALLR  ALLR   WK     2    0    0   1
```

Comment: There are many other coloumns also of which i dont need the count. e.g. df=pd.DataFrame(['BAT', 'BWL', 'ALLR']) df['1']=['BWL', 'BAT', 'ALLR'] df['2']=['BAT', 'BAT', 'WK'] df['3']=['A', 'B', 'C'] df #i dont need count of 'A','B','C, . Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @rakesh 2 ways , if there are lesser columns to select , then just do `pd.get_dummies(df[list_of_cols_to_select])` , or if there are less columns to drop do `pd.get_dummies(df.drop(list_of_cols_to_drop,1))` and use the same code for both the solutions this should work